# Logstash Failing to get data from collectd

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, collectd

MY collectd is sending data to logstash at port 25826 but i am seeing this error on running logstash

```
UDP listener died {:exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:160:in `bind'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-udp-2.0.5/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:67:in `udp_listener'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-udp-2.0.5/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:50:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `inputworker'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:336:in `start_input'"], :level=>:warn}
```

Anyone knows the solution out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got a fix**

> - > No error at Logstash the collector collectd was not sending the data
>   >     to logstash udp port corrected it by adding conf in network plugin of
>   >     collectd enabled that plugin in `collectd.conf` and replace hostname with logstash host and udp port.